# ASP.NET VB jQuery autocomplete JSON returning all data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, vb.net

I have a jQuery auto complete working fine with a database of products. I am now trying to change it so that it filters the data at the database depending on the input, so the application doesn't have to load all the data every time a user searches as it takes a long time.

The database currently holds 23,296 products.

The problem I have is when I do a search for 'Cordless Rotary Hammer Drill' the autocomplete filters the data correctly,  but it still takes a while to list them. In developer tools the response shows all 23,296 products have been returned as in the image below, so i guess this is why it's taking so long to load.

Is this how it's supposed to work?
Shouldn't the response only be the products that the sql query returns?

The search 'Cordless Rotary Hammer Drill' should only return 92 rows and if I directly to the autocomplete URL: http://mydomain/search.ProductSearch?filter=cordless%20Rotary%20Hammer%20Drill

then it only returns the 92 so i'm not sure why developer tools is getting all products in the response?

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

    var filter = $('#product').val();

    $("#product").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://mydomain/search.ProductSearch?filter=" + filter,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                type: 'Get',
                success: function (data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.Title,
                            id: item.Id
                        };
                    });

                    //call the filter here
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#product_id').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <label for="state">Product: </label>
    <input type="text" id="product"  name="product" />
    <input type="text" id="product_id" name="product_id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="form_submitted" name="form_submitted" value="true" />

</form>
```

**.NET**

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class ProductSearch
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim requestHttp As HttpRequest = context.Request
        Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response
        ' This handler is called whenever a file ending 
        ' in .sample is requested. A file with that extension
        ' does not need to exist.


        Dim SearchFilter As String = requestHttp.QueryString("filter")
        Dim HostDomain As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host


        'database connection from web.config file
        Dim ConnSql As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        ConnSql.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnSql").ConnectionString()

        'get amenity data
        Dim cmdSelect As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        cmdSelect.Connection = ConnSql
        cmdSelect.CommandText = "spSearchList"
        cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim pFilter As SqlParameter

        pFilter = New SqlParameter()
        pFilter.ParameterName = "@filter"
        pFilter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
        pFilter.Size = 200
        pFilter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        pFilter.Value = Trim(SearchFilter)

        cmdSelect.Parameters.Add(pFilter)

        'data adapter
        Dim daSelect As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        daSelect.SelectCommand = cmdSelect

        'data table
        Dim dtSelect As DataTable = New DataTable()
        daSelect.Fill(dtSelect)

        'data set
        Dim dsSelect As DataSet = New DataSet()
        daSelect.Fill(dsSelect, "Select")

        cmdSelect.Dispose()
        ConnSql.Close()


        If (dsSelect.Tables.Count > 0) And (dsSelect.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then

            Dim JSONData As String = DataTableToJSON(dtSelect)
            'Dim JSONData As String = "{ ""Products"":" & DataTableToJSON(dtSelect) & "}"
            response.ClearHeaders()
            response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
            response.Write(JSONData)

        End If


    End Sub

    Public Function DataTableToJSON(dt As DataTable) As String

        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = 50000000
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next

        Return serializer.Serialize(rows)

    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean _
            Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

**STORED PROC**

```
@filter nvarchar(200)

AS

SELECT

    [Id],
    [Code],
    [Title],
    [Make],
    [Model]

FROM [dbo].[Products]

WHERE [Title] LIKE '%' + @filter + '%'
```

Comment: Well from the code you posted I dont see any restriction of 92. In server side just return the top 92...

Comment: The URL request 'url: "http://mydomain/search.ProductSearch?filter=" + filter' passes the search term the user is typing to the sql query that filters the data and should filter the data depending on the parameter 'filter' that is passed.

Comment: but where do you restrict it to return 92 rows

Comment: It depends on what search term is entered, but when i search for 'Cordless Rotary Hammer Drill' it should return 92 rows. Which the autocomplete does, the direct url does but the response in developer tools gets all 23,000 products.

Comment: What is the value of `data: { term: request.term },` ? Have you tried using the debugger in both situations? I suspect the server code is reading the filter value from the request data, not the query string.

Comment: i've added my .NET code and SQL stored procedure in case thats any help.

Comment: @asawyer I just looked at what the values of 'request.term' & 'filter' where when I searched and 'filter' was blank, so i've updated my URL to: 'url: "http://mydomain/admin/search.ProductSearch?filter=" + request.term' and it works fine now. I can't except your answer as i'ts only a comment though.

Comment: You have some redundancies in your `DataAdapter`-related code.  You only need to fill one dataset and check it for rows.  You could also probably scaffold this with OData and Entity Framework and be done in around 5 minutes.  Your stored proc is also incompletely posted.

Comment: You can upvote his comment.

Comment: @JBoom Go ahead and write up exactly what was happening, why, and what you did to fix it, then accept that as the answer. That way the next person who reads this will have a better understanding with their problem.

Comment: @JBoom Just read your code. I *strongly urge* you to do some research on SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Your code is incredibly vulnerable it's not even funny. Someone could dump the entire contents of your database in a few minutes and it wouldn't even be that hard.